# Any way to check the validity of a Facebook feed dialog via direct URL's returned post_id?

Tags: facebook, dialog

I'm letting Facebook users post a link to their feed in exchange for something. For simplicity, I'd like to use the 'Direct URL' method of initializing a feed dialog

(see "Direct URL Example" @ http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/)

which I understand returns a `post_id` upon success. My question is: *is there anyway to check the validity of this post_id?*

Can I then query the Facebook API for confirmation of this `post_id`? Couldn't anybody just hit my `callback_uri` with the `post_id` parameter set and make it look like they successfully posted to their feed?

Comment: [Platform Policies and Promotions Checklist](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/policy/policy_checklist/english/) states:
*"App does not directly reward or require users to use Facebook Social channels, such as Feed stories and Requests."*

Answer (score 1):

You can check the existence of [`post`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/) by issuing request to [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) just after receiving callback in JS-SDK or visit of your `redirect_uri` for direct flow of [Feed Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) (you'll need an active user `access_token` to ensure that post is exists and `read_stream` permission to ensure that `post` created using your application):

```
https://graph.facebook.com/POST_ID?fields=id,application
```

Once you get the response you can check that `application`'s `id` in [`post`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/) is matching your application.

Comment: Here's my problem though ... If you're using the Direct URL method of getting a user to make a share, not the oauth authenticated (with read_stream access) method, then what can you do with that post_id that's being sent back? As far as I know you do not have a user token or read_stream access when you go through the direct URL method ...

Answer (score 0):

Here's the fun part.  I've experienced this first hand (as well as other stackoverflow users).  If you check the post_id via the api, it might return blank!!  But if you check after a short period of time (like 90 seconds), then it comes back with the data.  So you can check the validity of the post_id at a latter point, but not directly right away.

Comment: In that case, I don't need oauth read_stream access/extended permission/access tokens or anything to see the post?

Comment: It'll be great if you could link to other [so] questions/answers that describe that issue. As far as I've tested that functionality it worked smoothly without any lag between post publishing and post data retrieval...

Comment: I've seen this behavior as described by CFOS too, it just doesn't wanna give back anything straight away some times. If I wait, then it will work.

Comment: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/9031803/photos-addtag-returns-invalid-photo-id Here's a link to a question I've answered regarding this.  We'll see if @Coder has any input as well.